# 2 tables, need to set the rows with the maximum height for each matching row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 html tables, I need to have each row with the same height.

So if table#1's 3rd row has a height of 25, then table#2's 3rd row should have a height of 25.

Whichever matching row has the largest height, then both rows should have the same height.

How can I do this?

I know how to traverse the rows like:

```
$("table1 tr").each(function() {

});

$("table2 tr").each(function() {

});
```

Comment: is it a 1-to-1 count for rows? That is, will table 1 and table 2 always have the same number of rows?

Comment: Here's a similar question I ansewred before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351628/td-height-on-two-separate-tables/10351721#10351721 The difference being that will set height of all rows of the two tables, not just the tallest.

Comment: @Shmiddty yes the same # of rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this (assuming both tables have an equal amount of rows):

```
//for each row in table one
$("#table1 tr").each(function(index, element){

    //get row height from table1 and the corresponding row in table two
    var rowOneHeight = $(this).height();
    var rowTwo = $("#table2 tr:eq(" + index + ")");

    //if no matching row was found in table two, stop loop
    if(!rowTwo.length) return false;

    var rowTwoHeight = rowTwo.height();

    //compare row heights, and set the least high row to the height of the highest one
    if(rowOneHeight > rowTwoHeight){
        //set rowTwoHeight to rowOneHeight
        rowTwo.height(rowOneHeight);
    }else{
        $(this).height(rowTwoHeight);
    }
});
```

Comment: why not just use the index and element that's passed as arguments through `.each()`'s function.  `.each( function(index, Element) )`

Comment: You can also check the amount of rows before the each loop to see which one has more. (though technically you only need to loop over the one that has fewer, so I'm not sure this is necessary)

Comment: I updated, now it checks if a corresponding row exists before trying to update anything. Now all bases are covered I think. Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Actually, you should `return false;` if there is no row in the second table. There is no reason to keep iterating over table 1 if table2 has no more matching rows.

Comment: Sorry, rejected your edit too quickly. Update code accordingly

Comment: I get an error, saying `Object HTMLTableRowElement doesn't have a height method`.

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example here. http://jsfiddle.net/anAgent/ZcnEp/

When setting the height, you'll need to consider the border of the row as it will effect the height. My example doesn't include this bite of code, but it might be something you'll need to consider if you're setting borders.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $table1 = $("#Table1");
        var $table2 = $("#Table2");
        $.each($table1.find("tr"), function(i, o) {
            var $t1r = $(o);
            var $t2r = $table2.find('tr').eq(i);
            if ($t2r != undefined) {
                $t1r.height($t1r.height() > $t2r.height() ? $t1r.height() : $t2r.height());
                $t2r.height($t1r.height());
                console.log("t1:r%s | t2:r%s", $t1r.height(), $t2r.height());
            } else {
              return false;
            }
        });
    });​
```